# ignoring the next line if it is empty (i.e clicking enter twice between two paragraphs)

Tags: java

I am using a scanner that, by using redirection, reads a file and does something with the command that is provided each line. After it is done, it checks the next line to see if there is another command and so on (this is done in a do-while loop). It works perfectly fine if the format of the file is as follows

```
AddGame 1001 "Mirror's Edge"
AddGame 1002 "Dark Souls"
AddGame 1003 "Dishonored"
AddGame 1004 "Deadlight"
```

However, I want to be able to have a file where there may be a blank line in between commands and if that line is detected, simply skip that line and continue on to the next.

```
AddGame 1001 "Mirror's Edge"
AddGame 1002 "Dark Souls"

AddGame 1003 "Dishonored"
AddGame 1004 "Deadlight"
```

I was just wondering if there was any method already provided by java that does this for example like the trim() method to take out leading and trailing whitespace. If not, I can't seem to think of another way to just skip that line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)'s **nextLine()** method to get the line String instance and then [isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) method to test if it is empty and pass through if it is

```
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        if( (scanner.nextLine()).isEmpty() ){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            //do things...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I did think about doing this, I just didn't know how I could make it go to the next iteration of the loop. I guess it is because I did not know that continue was a keyword in java. Sorry I am not that in depth with Java. But your solution worked and I will give it the check mark once I can (have to wait 5 minutes before I can give it the check mark according to SO)

Comment: I'm glad to help you